# Can't reference Gson 2.2.4 JAR file in Eclipse

Tags: android, gson

I am pretty new to Android and has just started using JAR files. I want to convert my object to json by using Gson class. I have already downloaded gson-2.2.4 file & has imported it in my project

Here I have added Gson JAR in libs folder & also added it as external JAR.

[Image of my project where I included jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY0dI.png)

But even after including JAR files in my project, I am not able to use it's functionalities. When I try to make an object of Gson it does not take reference from Gson JAR file (at least that's what I think).

[Error while creating Gson class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM6U6.png)

Please help me solve this error. Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the jar file to your build/class paths?

Comment: I have added that jar file in Java Build Path >> Libraries.

Comment: Your Gson dependency has `sources` classifier -- you must reference the compiled artifact rather than its source bundle: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.4

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend you to use gradle dependency management to include the required libraries.

You just need to add additional line in your gradle app and press "Sync Now". That's it, now you are able use Gson in your project.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how to achieve this in Eclipse. @Fernando Tan

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your library and then in the "Ad as library" drop-down menu I hope and this works,
I highly recommend using Android Studio

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this in Eclipse. Thank you @Isa M

Comment: The truth is unknown, the best way to do it in a native IDE (Android Studio echo for Android development).
Greetings. @Meet Menhta

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.
As suggested by @Isa M. I right clicked my project->build path->Add Libraries.
Then select User Library
Add your external jars in that Library
Refresh your project & Done. You can now use libraries.